# is there any way to mask certain data but show the other data on land using cartopy?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I have two data, one is temperature data(image) and the other one is wind vector(q).
I'd like to show wind vector data on world map, on both land and ocean but mask temperature data on land. (Just be shown on ocean only.)
But when I try this with cfeature.LAND, both data are shown on land. How can I make this?

Here, my codes I've been writing.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12,10), subplot_kw = {'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)})
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.2)
for k, ax_ in enumerate(ax.flatten()):
    i, j = np.unravel_index(k, ax.shape)
    ax_.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 180+30, 30), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax_.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 50+30, 30), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax_.xaxis.set_major_formatter(LongitudeFormatter())
    ax_.yaxis.set_major_formatter(LatitudeFormatter())
    ax_.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=7)
    ax_.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, zorder=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='none')
    image = ax_.contourf(lon2d, lat2d, sst_stack[k,:,:], contour_levels, cmap='jet', extend='both', zorder=0, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()) # skt_stack[i,:,:]
    q = ax_.quiver(lon2d, lat2d, u_stack[k,:,:], v_stack[k,:,:], zorder=4, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), regrid_shape=10, scale_units='width')
    image = ax_.contourf(lon2d, lat2d, sst_stack[k,:,:], contour_levels, cmap='jet', extend='both', zorder=0, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()) # skt_stack[i,:,:]
    #qk = ax_.quiverkey(q, 0.9, 0.9, 2, label = 'm*s^-1', labelpos='E')
    ax_.coastlines()
    ax_.set_title(titles[k], loc='left', fontsize=10)



caxes = fig.add_axes([0.3, 0.15, 0.4, 0.015])
cbar = plt.colorbar(image, cax=caxes, orientation='horizontal', ticks=contour_levels, format='%d', drawedges=True)
cbar.set_label(label='degrees (c)', fontsize=7)
tick_locs = np.linspace(275, 305, 6)
cbar_tick_label = np.arange(275, 305, 5)
cbar.set_ticks(tick_locs)
cbar.set_ticklabels(cbar_tick_label)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=6)


plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.2)
plt.suptitle('Steering wind & SST climatological mean', fontsize=11)
plt.show()
```

ps. It's impossible to use the library Basemap for the time being.

Comment: Use `zorder` to arrange orders of the plot. Features with higher value of zorder will be above the ones with lower values. For example, `ax_.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, zorder=100, ...)`.